# Display a record based on multi-select picklist value

Tags: visualforce, picklist

I would like to show/hide records in VF if a value exists in a multi-select picklist.

Typically to render something true or false, I use `==` to check.  However, I can't do this with a mutli-select picklist.

Thoughts?  I am thinking something like the following needs to happen:

```
rendered="{!IF(contactskill.areas_of_expertise__c.contains(skill), true, false)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONTAINS` seems to be working  here, its from allowed [functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) for Visualforce.

```
rendered="{!CONTAINS(contactskill.areas_of_expertise__c, 'skill')}"
```

Based on your requirement you can use `OR` or `AND` functions to render based on multiple values:

```
rendered="{!OR(
    CONTAINS(contactskill.areas_of_expertise__c, 'option 1'),
    CONTAINS(contactskill.areas_of_expertise__c, 'option 2')
    )}"
```

Comment: This works beautifully!!!!  I am very, very happy!!!!!